# cmake build executable with relative paths for dependencies (relocatable executable)

Tags: c++, cmake, executable, configure

I have a package that is using cmake as its compiler. If I install the dependencies it needs first using a package manager then run `cmake` e.g.

```
$ sompackage-manager install depend1 depend2

$ wget http://a.b.c/somepackage.tgz

$ tar -xf somepackage.tgz

$ cd somepackage/

$ ls
```

> ```
> CI     CMakeFiles  CONTRIBUTING.md   README.md 
> CMakeCache.txt CMakeLists.txt  doc      LICENSE
> ```

```
cmake .
```

This will work fine. cmake finds all the dependencies and the project will create a folder in the build directory named `bin` that the executable will be in. I can then move the executable where ever id like. I assume the executable either knows the full path of the dependencies or has a list of full paths to check.

What id like to do is this:
  create a folder like `$HOME/newpackage`. Then install the dependencies (the dependencies happens to use a configure script) to that directory e.g.

```
$ mkdir $HOME/newpackage/depend1

$ wget http://a.b.c/depnd1.tgz

$ tar -xf depend1.tgz

$ cd depend1

$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/newpackage/depend1
```

Once all the dependencies are installed to `$HOME/newpackage/depend1`
Id then like to go back to the `somepackage` build directory and tell cmake to build the package to `$HOME/newpackage/` dir but also to look for the dependencies relative to where the executable is i.e a path like `./`. The end result would allow me to move the `newpackage` directory with the executable and the dependencies folders without breaking any paths.

I am having trouble finding the right cmake options or wether or not they are available.

Is this possible with cmake and what is the best way to go forward?

Comment: `what is the best way to go forward?` - You may start with wiki [CMake RPATH handling](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling). As you want to have executable and libraries to be relocatable as whole, using `$ORIGIN` in *RPATH* could be your choice.

Comment: @Tsyvarev. I want to clarify I am just building someone else's package and not writing or the writer of the `CMakeLists.txt` used for the build. Also I do not have a lot of experience with `cmake`. Can your suggestion be implemented with command line options while building with the `cmake` tool or is this something I would need to change in `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Usually packages are not relocatable in a way you want. You need to change `CMakeLists.txt` for achive such feature.

Comment: @Tsyvarev could you show a very simplified `CMakeLists.txt` that would achieve this? Maybe posted as a answer.

Comment: No, I cannot. It would be simple with a internal library linked to your executable. But with external library, searched by `find_package`, the things become much more tricky.

Comment: You really can't afford `find_package` for such a kind of build. Unless you consider a containerized deployment (à la docker)